# option to "import package" in Pycharm no longer available

Tags: python, pycharm

Before, when I would instantiate a class that I haven't imported, I would be able to hover over the class (or whatever was missing), and see an option to import it like the screenshot

[image]

Where it says "Create class" I would have the option to import the package. Since I updated my pycharm to 2021.3.1, that option seems to be gone for external packages. It still seems to work for internal packages, say, json. This is vital to my productivity. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: When I've seen PyCharm do this, it usually needs a little more help figuring out the package name, like `somepackage.HubSpot()`. I'm not sure I've ever seen it figure out a 3rd party module from just a class name.

Comment: Weird. It's always worked for me. Even with functions it will give me options for importing just that function.

Comment: Is `HubSpot` marked in one of your `source` directories via the project structure?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your `Project Structure` looks like, showing the `Content Roots`, and where these files are relative to each other. My first thought is that something got fubar'd with that. I've never had to do `somepackage.HubSpot()`, but I'm not on that version either.

Comment: I guess `HubSpot` is some external package. Are you using the python version you think you are that has that installed?

Comment: HubSpot is an external package. And yeah, just checked the interpreter in PyCharm and it's pointing to the correct virtual environment.

Comment: If you want help you'll probably need to provide some screenshots of your configuration. If you manually import it, is it found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting and recreating my .idea directory in pycharm. Once I did this, the problem was resolved.